# cannot resolve symbols in androidmanifest.xml while developing flutter application

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am developing a flutter application, it is working fine. In order to publish the app to the play store, I have to make some changes in the manifest.xml file.

I want to change the icon and the label of the application. I changed the android:label to my label but it is not reflecting when I run the application.
I have specified the icon:  android:icon="@drawable/app_logo.png", but it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'drawable' "
Even the GradleException is working the same as drawable.
I tried answer like setting the SDK path in the project structure but it did not work.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

delete the ".png"

you should use
`android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"`
instead of
`android:icon="@drawable/app_logo.png"`